# Simple example of Pandas ExtensionArray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It seems to me that Pandas `ExtensionArray`s would be one of the cases where a simple example to get one started would really help. However, I have not found a simple enough example anywhere.

#### Creating an `ExtensionArray`

To create an `ExtensionArray`, you need to

- Create an [`ExtensionDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype.html#pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype) and [register it](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_extension_dtype.html)
- Create an [`ExtensionArray`](https://dev.pandas.io/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html?highlight=extensionarray) by implementing the required methods.

There is also a [section in the Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extension-types) with a brief overview.

#### Example implementations

There are many examples of implementations:

- Pandas' own [internal extension arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/f48308099301a42d9afa35834af3ef2b117e5c93/pandas/core/arrays)
- [Geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas)' [`GeometryArray`](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/83ab5c63890a2575b95ede6b8a8ef469753c9605/geopandas/array.py#L261)
- Pandas documentation has a [list of projects with extension data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/ecosystem.html?highlight=cyberpandas#extension-data-types)

  - e.g. [CyberPandas](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/cyberpandas)' [`IPArray`](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/cyberpandas/blob/dbce13f94a75145a59d7a7981a8a07571a2e5eb6/cyberpandas/ip_array.py#L58)
- Many others around the web, for example [Fletcher](https://github.com/xhochy/fletcher)'s [`StringSupportingExtensionArray`](https://github.com/xhochy/fletcher/blob/39ce11d71e4ac1e95725d46be21bb38f3ea04349/fletcher/string_mixin.py#L20)

#### Question

Despite having studied all of the above, I still find extension arrays difficult to understand. All of the examples have a lot of specifics and custom functionality that makes it difficult to work out what is actually necessary. I suspect many have faced a similar problem.

I am thus asking for a **simple** and **minimal** example of a working `ExtensionArray`. The class should pass [all the tests Pandas have provided](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#testing-extension-arrays) to check that the `ExtensionArray` behaves as expected. I've provided an example implementation of the tests below.

To have a concrete example, let's say I want to extend `ExtensionArray` to obtain an integer array that is able to hold NA values. That is essentially [`IntegerArray`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f48308099301a42d9afa35834af3ef2b117e5c93/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py#L236), but stripped of any actual functionality beyond the basics of `ExtensionArray`.

---

## Testing the solution

I have used the following fixtures & tests to test the validity of the solution. These are based on the directions in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#testing-extension-arrays)

```py
import operator

import numpy as np
from pandas import Series
import pytest

from pandas.tests.extension.base.casting import BaseCastingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.constructors import BaseConstructorsTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.dtype import BaseDtypeTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.getitem import BaseGetitemTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.groupby import BaseGroupbyTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.interface import BaseInterfaceTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.io import BaseParsingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.methods import BaseMethodsTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.missing import BaseMissingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.ops import (  # noqa
    BaseArithmeticOpsTests,
    BaseComparisonOpsTests,
    BaseOpsUtil,
    BaseUnaryOpsTests,
)
from pandas.tests.extension.base.printing import BasePrintingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.reduce import (  # noqa
    BaseBooleanReduceTests,
    BaseNoReduceTests,
    BaseNumericReduceTests,
)
from pandas.tests.extension.base.reshaping import BaseReshapingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.setitem import BaseSetitemTests  # noqa

from .extension import NullableIntArray



@pytest.fixture
def dtype():
    """A fixture providing the ExtensionDtype to validate."""
    return 'NullableInt'


@pytest.fixture
def data():
    """
    Length-100 array for this type.
    * data[0] and data[1] should both be non missing
    * data[0] and data[1] should not be equal
    """
    return NullableIntArray(np.array(list(range(100))))


@pytest.fixture
def data_for_twos():
    """Length-100 array in which all the elements are two."""
    return NullableIntArray(np.array([2] * 2))


@pytest.fixture
def data_missing():
    """Length-2 array with [NA, Valid]"""
    return NullableIntArray(np.array([np.nan, 2]))


@pytest.fixture(params=["data", "data_missing"])
def all_data(request, data, data_missing):
    """Parametrized fixture giving 'data' and 'data_missing'"""
    if request.param == "data":
        return data
    elif request.param == "data_missing":
        return data_missing


@pytest.fixture
def data_repeated(data):
    """
    Generate many datasets.
    Parameters
    ----------
    data : fixture implementing `data`
    Returns
    -------
    Callable[[int], Generator]:
        A callable that takes a `count` argument and
        returns a generator yielding `count` datasets.
    """

    def gen(count):
        for _ in range(count):
            yield data

    return gen


@pytest.fixture
def data_for_sorting():
    """
    Length-3 array with a known sort order.
    This should be three items [B, C, A] with
    A < B < C
    """
    return NullableIntArray(np.array([2, 3, 1]))


@pytest.fixture
def data_missing_for_sorting():
    """
    Length-3 array with a known sort order.
    This should be three items [B, NA, A] with
    A < B and NA missing.
    """
    return NullableIntArray(np.array([2, np.nan, 1]))


@pytest.fixture
def na_cmp():
    """
    Binary operator for comparing NA values.
    Should return a function of two arguments that returns
    True if both arguments are (scalar) NA for your type.
    By default, uses ``operator.is_``
    """
    return operator.is_


@pytest.fixture
def na_value():
    """The scalar missing value for this type. Default 'None'"""
    return np.nan


@pytest.fixture
def data_for_grouping():
    """
    Data for factorization, grouping, and unique tests.
    Expected to be like [B, B, NA, NA, A, A, B, C]
    Where A < B < C and NA is missing
    """
    return NullableIntArray(np.array([2, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 3]))


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def box_in_series(request):
    """Whether to box the data in a Series"""
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(
    params=[
        lambda x: 1,
        lambda x: [1] * len(x),
        lambda x: Series([1] * len(x)),
        lambda x: x,
    ],
    ids=["scalar", "list", "series", "object"],
)
def groupby_apply_op(request):
    """
    Functions to test groupby.apply().
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def as_frame(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support Series and Series.to_frame() comparison testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def as_series(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support arr and Series(arr) comparison testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def use_numpy(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support comparison testing of ExtensionDtype array
    and numpy array.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=["ffill", "bfill"])
def fillna_method(request):
    """
    Parametrized fixture giving method parameters 'ffill' and 'bfill' for
    Series.fillna(method=<method>) testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def as_array(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support ExtensionDtype _from_sequence method testing.
    """
    return request.param


class TestCastingTests(BaseCastingTests):
    pass


class TestConstructorsTests(BaseConstructorsTests):
    pass



class TestDtypeTests(BaseDtypeTests):
    pass


class TestGetitemTests(BaseGetitemTests):
    pass


class TestGroupbyTests(BaseGroupbyTests):
    pass


class TestInterfaceTests(BaseInterfaceTests):
    pass


class TestParsingTests(BaseParsingTests):
    pass


class TestMethodsTests(BaseMethodsTests):
    pass


class TestMissingTests(BaseMissingTests):
    pass


class TestArithmeticOpsTests(BaseArithmeticOpsTests):
    pass


class TestComparisonOpsTests(BaseComparisonOpsTests):
    pass


class TestOpsUtil(BaseOpsUtil):
    pass


class TestUnaryOpsTests(BaseUnaryOpsTests):
    pass


class TestPrintingTests(BasePrintingTests):
    pass


class TestBooleanReduceTests(BaseBooleanReduceTests):
    pass


class TestNoReduceTests(BaseNoReduceTests):
    pass


class TestNumericReduceTests(BaseNumericReduceTests):
    pass


class TestReshapingTests(BaseReshapingTests):
    pass


class TestSetitemTests(BaseSetitemTests):
    pass
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Update 2021-09-19

There were too many issues trying to get `NullableIntArray` to pass the [test suite](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/extension/base/__init__.py), so I've created a new example (`AngleDtype` + `AngleArray`) that currently passes 398 tests (fails 2).

---

### 0. Usage

<sup>*(pandas 1.3.2, numpy 1.20.2, python 3.9.2)*</sup>

`AngleArray` stores either radians or degrees depending on its `unit` (represented by `AngleDtype`):

```
thetas = [0, np.pi, 2 * np.pi]
a = AngleArray(thetas, unit='rad')
# <AngleArray>
# [0.0, 3.141592653589793, 6.283185307179586]
# Length: 3, dtype: angle[rad]
```

```
a = a.asunit('deg')
# <AngleArray>
# [0.0, 180.0, 360.0]
# Length: 3, dtype: angle[deg]
```

`AngleArray` can be stored in a `Series` or `DataFrame`:

```
s = pd.Series(a)
# 0     0.0
# 1   180.0
# 2   360.0
# dtype: angle[deg]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': s, 'b': AngleArray(thetas[::-1])})
#        a                  b
# 0    0.0  6.283185307179586
# 1  180.0  3.141592653589793
# 2  360.0                0.0
```

```
df['a']
# 0    0.0
# 1  180.0
# 2  360.0
# Name: a, dtype: angle[deg]
```

```
df['b']
# 0  6.283185307179586
# 1  3.141592653589793
# 2                0.0
# Name: b, dtype: angle[rad]
```

`AngleArray` computations are `unit`-aware:

```
df['a + b'] = df['a'] + df['b']
#        a                  b  a + b
# 0    0.0  6.283185307179586  360.0
# 1  180.0  3.141592653589793  360.0
# 2  360.0                0.0  360.0
```

```
df['a + b']
# 0   360.0
# 1   360.0
# 2   360.0
# Name: a + b, dtype: angle[deg]
```

---

### 1. `AngleDtype`

For *every* `ExtensionDtype`, [3 methods must be implemented](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/73c68257545b5f8530b7044f56647bd2db92e2ba/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py#L47-L52) concretely:

- `type`
- `name`
- `construct_array_type`

For a *parameterized* `ExtensionDtype` (e.g., `AngleDtype.unit` or `PeriodDtype.freq`):

- [`_metadata` is required](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/73c68257545b5f8530b7044f56647bd2db92e2ba/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py#L70)
- [`construct_from_string` is recommended](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/73c68257545b5f8530b7044f56647bd2db92e2ba/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py#L213)

For the *test suite:*

- `__hash__`
- `__eq__`
- `__setstate__`

```
from __future__ import annotations

import operator
import re
from typing import Any, Sequence

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


@pd.api.extensions.register_extension_dtype
class AngleDtype(pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.PandasExtensionDtype):
    """
    An ExtensionDtype for unit-aware angular data.
    """
    # Required for all parameterized dtypes
    _metadata = ('unit',)
    _match = re.compile(r'(A|a)ngle\[(?P<unit>.+)\]')

    def __init__(self, unit=None):
        if unit is None:
            unit = 'rad'

        if unit not in ['rad', 'deg']:
            msg = f"'{type(self).__name__}' only supports 'rad' and 'deg' units"
            raise ValueError(msg)

        self._unit = unit

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'angle[{self.unit}]'

    # TestDtypeTests
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(str(self))

    # TestDtypeTests
    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.name == other
        else:
            return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self.unit == other.unit

    # Required for pickle compat (see GH26067)
    def __setstate__(self, state) -> None:
        self._unit = state['unit']

    # Required for all ExtensionDtype subclasses
    @classmethod
    def construct_array_type(cls):
        """
        Return the array type associated with this dtype.
        """
        return AngleArray

    # Recommended for parameterized dtypes
    @classmethod
    def construct_from_string(cls, string: str) -> AngleDtype:
        """
        Construct an AngleDtype from a string.

        Example
        -------
        >>> AngleDtype.construct_from_string('angle[deg]')
        angle['deg']
        """
        if not isinstance(string, str):
            msg = f"'construct_from_string' expects a string, got {type(string)}"
            raise TypeError(msg)

        msg = f"Cannot construct a '{cls.__name__}' from '{string}'"
        match = cls._match.match(string)

        if match:
            d = match.groupdict()
            try:
                return cls(unit=d['unit'])
            except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError) as err:
                raise TypeError(msg) from err
        else:
            raise TypeError(msg)

    # Required for all ExtensionDtype subclasses
    @property
    def type(self):
        """
        The scalar type for the array (e.g., int).
        """
        return np.generic

    # Required for all ExtensionDtype subclasses
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        """
        A string representation of the dtype.
        """
        return str(self)

    @property
    def unit(self) -> str:
        """
        The angle unit.
        """
        return self._unit
```

---

### 2. `AngleArray`

For *every* `ExtensionArray`, [11 methods must be implemented](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e7e7b40722e421ef7e519c645d851452c70a7b7c/pandas/core/arrays/base.py#L144) concretely:

- `_from_sequence`
- `_from_factorized`
- `__getitem__`
- `__len__`
- `__eq__`
- `dtype`
- `nbytes`
- `isna`
- `take`
- `copy`
- `_concat_same_type`

For the *test suite:*

- **Many** more concrete methods are needed
- Whenever a test prompted me to add a new method, I marked it with a comment (though this is not a comprehensive mapping since most methods are required by multiple tests)

```
class AngleArray(pd.api.extensions.ExtensionArray):
    """
    An ExtensionArray for unit-aware angular data.
    """
    # Include `copy` param for TestInterfaceTests
    def __init__(self, data, unit='rad', copy: bool=False):
        self._data = np.array(data, copy=copy)
        self._unit = unit

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> AngleArray | Any:
        """
        Select a subset of self.
        """
        if isinstance(index, int):
            return self._data[index]
        else:
            # Check index for TestGetitemTests
            index = pd.core.indexers.check_array_indexer(self, index)
            return type(self)(self._data[index])

    # TestSetitemTests
    def __setitem__(self, index: int, value: np.generic) -> None:
        """
        Set one or more values in-place.
        """
        # Check index for TestSetitemTests
        index = pd.core.indexers.check_array_indexer(self, index)

        # Upcast to value's type (if needed) for TestMethodsTests
        if self._data.dtype < type(value):
            self._data = self._data.astype(type(value))

        # TODO: Validate value for TestSetitemTests
        # value = self._validate_setitem_value(value)

        self._data[index] = value

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        """
        Length of this array.
        """
        return len(self._data)

    # TestUnaryOpsTests
    def __invert__(self) -> AngleArray:
        """
        Element-wise inverse of this array.
        """
        data = ~self._data
        return type(self)(data, unit=self.dtype.unit)

    def _ensure_same_units(self, other) -> AngleArray:
        """
        Helper method to ensure `self` and `other` have the same units.
        """
        if isinstance(other, type(self)) and self.dtype.unit != other.dtype.unit:
            return other.asunit(self.dtype.unit)
        else:
            return other

    def _apply_operator(self, op, other, recast=False) -> np.ndarray | AngleArray:
        """
        Helper method to apply an operator `op` between `self` and `other`.

        Some ops require the result to be recast into AngleArray:
        * Comparison ops: recast=False
        * Arithmetic ops: recast=True
        """
        f = operator.attrgetter(op)
        data, other = np.array(self), np.array(self._ensure_same_units(other))
        result = f(data)(other)
        return result if not recast else type(self)(result, unit=self.dtype.unit)

    def _apply_operator_if_not_series(self, op, other, recast=False) -> np.ndarray | AngleArray:
        """
        Wraps _apply_operator only if `other` is not Series/DataFrame.
        
        Some ops should return NotImplemented if `other` is a Series/DataFrame:
        https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e7e7b40722e421ef7e519c645d851452c70a7b7c/pandas/tests/extension/base/ops.py#L115
        """
        if isinstance(other, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)):
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return self._apply_operator(op, other, recast=recast)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__eq__')
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator('__eq__', other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__ne__')
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator('__ne__', other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__lt__')
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator('__lt__', other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__gt__')
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator('__gt__', other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__le__')
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator('__le__', other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__ge__')
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator('__ge__', other, recast=False)
    
    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__add__')
    def __add__(self, other) -> AngleArray:
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series('__add__', other, recast=True)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__sub__')
    def __sub__(self, other) -> AngleArray:
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series('__sub__', other, recast=True)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__mul__')
    def __mul__(self, other) -> AngleArray:
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series('__mul__', other, recast=True)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer('__truediv__')
    def __truediv__(self, other) -> AngleArray:
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series('__truediv__', other, recast=True)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @classmethod
    def _from_sequence(cls, data, dtype=None, copy: bool=False):
        """
        Construct a new AngleArray from a sequence of scalars.
        """
        if dtype is None:
            dtype = AngleDtype()

        if not isinstance(dtype, AngleDtype):
            msg = f"'{cls.__name__}' only supports 'AngleDtype' dtype"
            raise ValueError(msg)
        else:
            return cls(data, unit=dtype.unit, copy=copy)

    # TestParsingTests
    @classmethod
    def _from_sequence_of_strings(cls, strings, *, dtype=None, copy: bool=False) -> AngleArray:
        """
        Construct a new AngleArray from a sequence of strings.
        """
        scalars = pd.to_numeric(strings, errors='raise')
        return cls._from_sequence(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @classmethod
    def _from_factorized(cls, uniques: np.ndarray, original: AngleArray):
        """
        Reconstruct an AngleArray after factorization.
        """
        return cls(uniques, unit=original.dtype.unit)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @classmethod
    def _concat_same_type(cls, to_concat: Sequence[AngleArray]) -> AngleArray:
        """
        Concatenate multiple AngleArrays.
        """
        # ensure same units
        counts = pd.value_counts([array.dtype.unit for array in to_concat])
        unit = counts.index[0]

        if counts.size > 1:
            to_concat = [a.asunit(unit) for a in to_concat]

        return cls(np.concatenate(to_concat), unit=unit)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @property
    def dtype(self):
        """
        An instance of AngleDtype.
        """
        return AngleDtype(self._unit)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @property
    def nbytes(self) -> int:
        """
        The number of bytes needed to store this object in memory.
        """
        return self._data.nbytes

    @property
    def unit(self):
        return self.dtype.unit

    # Test*ReduceTests
    def all(self) -> bool:
        return all(self)

    def any(self) -> bool:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return any(self)

    def sum(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._data.sum()

    def mean(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._data.mean()

    def max(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._data.max()

    def min(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._data.min()

    def prod(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._data.prod()

    def std(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._data).std()

    def var(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._data).var()

    def median(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return np.median(self._data)

    def skew(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._data).skew()

    def kurt(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._data).kurt()

    # Test*ReduceTests
    def _reduce(self, name: str, *, skipna: bool=True, **kwargs):
        """
        Return a scalar result of performing the reduction operation.
        """
        f = operator.attrgetter(name)
        return f(self)()

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    def isna(self):
        """
        A 1-D array indicating if each value is missing.
        """
        return pd.isnull(self._data)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    def copy(self):
        """
        Return a copy of the array.
        """
        copied = self._data.copy()
        return type(self)(copied, unit=self.unit)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    def take(self, indices, allow_fill=False, fill_value=None):
        """
        Take elements from an array.
        """
        if allow_fill and fill_value is None:
            fill_value = self.dtype.na_value

        result = pd.core.algorithms.take(self._data, indices, allow_fill=allow_fill,
                                         fill_value=fill_value)
        return self._from_sequence(result)

    # TestMethodsTests
    def value_counts(self, dropna: bool=True):
        """
        Return a Series containing descending counts of unique values (excludes NA values by default).
        """
        return pd.core.algorithms.value_counts(self._data, dropna=dropna)

    def asunit(self, unit: str) -> AngleArray:
        """
        Cast to an AngleDtype unit.
        """
        if unit not in ['rad', 'deg']:
            msg = f"'{type(self.dtype).__name__}' only supports 'rad' and 'deg' units"
            raise ValueError(msg)
        elif self.dtype.unit == unit:
            return self
        else:
            rad2deg = self.dtype.unit == 'rad' and unit == 'deg'
            data = np.rad2deg(self._data) if rad2deg else np.deg2rad(self._data)
            return type(self)(data, unit)
```

---

### 3. `pytest`

```
$ pytest tests.py
...
2 failed, 398 passed, 1 skipped, 1 xfailed in 3.95s
```

There are two remaining test failures:

1. [`TestMethodsTests.test_combine_le`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/011c016f6106cf08df45cf069863fc0b1397b84e/pandas/tests/extension/base/methods.py#L264)

   Currently this returns an `AngleDtype` Series of boolean values, but pandas wants the Series itself to be boolean (not sure how to resolve this without breaking other tests):

   ```
   pd.Series(a).combine(pd.Series(a), lambda x1, x2: x1 <= x2)
   ```
2. [`TestSetitemTests.test_setitem_scalar_key_sequence_raise`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/011c016f6106cf08df45cf069863fc0b1397b84e/pandas/tests/extension/base/setitem.py#L321)

   Currently this puts `a[[0, 1]]` into index 0, but pandas expects an error:

   ```
   a[0] = a[[0, 1]]
   ```

   Several of the pandas extension arrays use convoluted validation methods to catch these edge cases, e.g.:

   - [`DatetimeLikeArrayMixin._validate_setitem_value`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e7e7b40722e421ef7e519c645d851452c70a7b7c/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py#L759)
   - [`DatetimeLikeArrayMixin._validate_listlike`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e7e7b40722e421ef7e519c645d851452c70a7b7c/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py#L701)
   - [`DatetimeLikeArrayMixin._validate_scalar`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e7e7b40722e421ef7e519c645d851452c70a7b7c/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py#L615)

```
import operator

import numpy as np
from pandas import Series
import pytest

from pandas.tests.extension.base.casting import BaseCastingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.constructors import BaseConstructorsTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.dtype import BaseDtypeTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.getitem import BaseGetitemTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.groupby import BaseGroupbyTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.interface import BaseInterfaceTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.io import BaseParsingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.methods import BaseMethodsTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.missing import BaseMissingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.ops import (  # noqa
    BaseArithmeticOpsTests,
    BaseComparisonOpsTests,
    BaseOpsUtil,
    BaseUnaryOpsTests,
)
from pandas.tests.extension.base.printing import BasePrintingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.reduce import (  # noqa
    BaseBooleanReduceTests,
    BaseNoReduceTests,
    BaseNumericReduceTests,
)
from pandas.tests.extension.base.reshaping import BaseReshapingTests  # noqa
from pandas.tests.extension.base.setitem import BaseSetitemTests  # noqa

from extension import AngleDtype, AngleArray


@pytest.fixture
def dtype():
    """
    A fixture providing the ExtensionDtype to validate.
    """
    return AngleDtype()


@pytest.fixture
def data():
    """
    Length-100 array for this type.
    * data[0] and data[1] should both be non missing
    * data[0] and data[1] should not be equal
    """
    return AngleArray(np.arange(100))


@pytest.fixture
def data_for_twos():
    """
    Length-100 array in which all the elements are two.
    """
    return AngleArray(np.array([2] * 100))


@pytest.fixture
def data_missing():
    """
    Length-2 array with [NA, Valid].
    """
    return AngleArray(np.array([np.nan, 2]))


@pytest.fixture(params=['data', 'data_missing'])
def all_data(request, data, data_missing):
    """
    Parameterized fixture giving 'data' and 'data_missing'.
    """
    if request.param == 'data':
        return data
    elif request.param == 'data_missing':
        return data_missing


@pytest.fixture
def data_repeated(data):
    """
    Generate many datasets.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : fixture implementing `data`

    Returns
    -------
    Callable[[int], Generator]:
        A callable that takes a `count` argument and
        returns a generator yielding `count` datasets.
    """
    def gen(count):
        for _ in range(count):
            yield data

    return gen


@pytest.fixture
def data_for_sorting():
    """
    Length-3 array with a known sort order.
    This should be three items [B, C, A] with A < B < C.
    """
    return AngleArray(np.array([2, 3, 1]))


@pytest.fixture
def data_missing_for_sorting():
    """
    Length-3 array with a known sort order.
    This should be three items [B, NA, A] with A < B and NA missing.
    """
    return AngleArray(np.array([2, np.nan, 1]))


@pytest.fixture
def na_cmp():
    """
    Binary operator for comparing NA values.
    Should return a function of two arguments that returns
    True if both arguments are (scalar) NA for your type.
    By default, uses ``operator.is_``.
    """
    return lambda a, b: np.array_equal(a, b, equal_nan=True)


@pytest.fixture
def na_value():
    """
    The scalar missing value for this type. Default 'None'.
    """
    return np.nan


@pytest.fixture
def data_for_grouping():
    """
    Data for factorization, grouping, and unique tests.
    Expected to be like [B, B, NA, NA, A, A, B, C] where A < B < C and NA is missing.
    """
    return AngleArray(np.array([2, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 3]))


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def box_in_series(request):
    """
    Whether to box the data in a Series.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(
    params=[
        lambda x: 1,
        lambda x: [1] * len(x),
        lambda x: Series([1] * len(x)),
        lambda x: x,
    ],
    ids=['scalar', 'list', 'series', 'object'],
)
def groupby_apply_operator(request):
    """
    Functions to test groupby.apply().
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def as_frame(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support Series and Series.to_frame() comparison testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def as_series(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support arr and Series(arr) comparison testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def use_numpy(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support comparison testing of ExtensionDtype array    and numpy array.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=['ffill', 'bfill'])
def fillna_method(request):
    """
    Parameterized fixture giving method parameters 'ffill' and 'bfill' for
    Series.fillna(method=<method>) testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def as_array(request):
    """
    Boolean fixture to support ExtensionDtype _from_sequence method testing.
    """
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[None, lambda x: x])
def sort_by_key(request):
    """
    Simple fixture for testing keys in sorting methods.
    Tests None (no key) and the identity key.
    """
    return request.param


# TODO: Finish implementing all operators
_all_arithmetic_operators = [
    '__add__',
    #  '__radd__',
    '__sub__',
    #  '__rsub__',
    '__mul__',
    #  '__rmul__',
    #  '__floordiv__',
    #  '__rfloordiv__',
    '__truediv__',
    #  '__rtruediv__',
    #  '__pow__',
    #  '__rpow__',
    #  '__mod__',
    #  '__rmod__',
]
@pytest.fixture(params=_all_arithmetic_operators)
def all_arithmetic_operators(request):
    """
    Fixture for dunder names for common arithmetic operations.
    """
    return request.param


_all_numeric_reductions = [
    'sum',
    'max',
    'min',
    'mean',
    'prod',
    'std',
    'var',
    'median',
    'kurt',
    'skew',
]
@pytest.fixture(params=_all_numeric_reductions)
def all_numeric_reductions(request):
    """
    Fixture for numeric reduction names.
    """
    return request.param


_all_boolean_reductions = ['all', 'any']
@pytest.fixture(params=_all_boolean_reductions)
def all_boolean_reductions(request):
    """
    Fixture for boolean reduction names.
    """
    return request.param


_all_reductions = _all_numeric_reductions + _all_boolean_reductions
@pytest.fixture(params=_all_reductions)
def all_reductions(request):
    """
    Fixture for all (boolean + numeric) reduction names.
    """
    return request.param


_all_compare_operators = [
    '__eq__',
    '__ne__',
    '__le__',
    '__lt__',
    '__ge__',
    '__gt__',
]
@pytest.fixture(params=_all_compare_operators)
def all_compare_operators(request):
    """
    Fixture for dunder names for common compare operations:

    * >=
    * >
    * ==
    * !=
    * <
    * <=
    """
    return request.param


class TestCastingTests(BaseCastingTests):
    pass


class TestConstructorsTests(BaseConstructorsTests):
    pass


class TestDtypeTests(BaseDtypeTests):
    pass


class TestGetitemTests(BaseGetitemTests):
    pass


class TestGroupbyTests(BaseGroupbyTests):
    pass


class TestInterfaceTests(BaseInterfaceTests):
    pass


class TestParsingTests(BaseParsingTests):
    pass


class TestMethodsTests(BaseMethodsTests):
    pass


class TestMissingTests(BaseMissingTests):
    pass


class TestArithmeticOpsTests(BaseArithmeticOpsTests):
    series_scalar_exc = None
    frame_scalar_exc = None
    series_array_exc = None
    divmod_exc = TypeError  # TODO: Implement divmod


class TestComparisonOpsTests(BaseComparisonOpsTests):
    # See pint-pandas test suite
    def _compare_other(self, s, data, op_name, other):
        op = self.get_op_from_name(op_name)
        result = op(s, other)
        expected = op(s.to_numpy(), other)
        assert (result == expected).all()


class TestOpsUtil(BaseOpsUtil):
    pass


class TestUnaryOpsTests(BaseUnaryOpsTests):
    pass


class TestPrintingTests(BasePrintingTests):
    pass


class TestBooleanReduceTests(BaseBooleanReduceTests):
    pass


class TestNumericReduceTests(BaseNumericReduceTests):
    pass


# AFAICT NoReduce and Boolean+NumericReduce are mutually exclusive
# class TestNoReduceTests(BaseNoReduceTests):
    # pass


class TestReshapingTests(BaseReshapingTests):
    pass


class TestSetitemTests(BaseSetitemTests):
    pass
```

Comment: Great explanantion!

Comment: Thanks for this answer and sorry it took me so long to get back to it. Can you please extend this so that it's actually fully usable in a dataframe? For example, `pd.DataFrame(NullableIntArray([0]*100))` throws `AbstractMethodError: This method must be defined in the concrete class NullableIntArray` since `__len__` is not implemented.

Comment: Trying out the [tests](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#testing-extension-arrays) to ensure that the "extension arrays satisfy the expected behavior" with some basic fixtures yields 308 fails and 20 passes for me. Many/most of these might be just `__len__` and some other basics not being implemented though. I have added the code I used for the test into the question.

Comment: Other likely problems: I think you must also implement a basic `ExtensionDtype`, a string is not expected/accepted. Moreover many of the required methods from [`ExtensionArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html#pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray) are not yet implemented.

Comment: Sorry that my question wasn't clear about this: I expected the `ExtensionArray` to be usable within Pandas, not just as a standalone object. If you think this is outside the scope now, I will probably start a new question. Let me please know.

Comment: @Dahn Ah ok, I misunderstood. For the dtype, I had actually written a basic `NullableInt` dtype (i.e., a proper `ExtensionDtype`), but I left it out because I thought you wanted something simpler. I'll clean up the dtype this weekend and post it. I'll also check out the pytests and see how many more concrete methods are needed.

Comment: @Dahn I've updated the answer with a full `ExtensionDtype` + `ExtensionArray` example (pass:fail = 398:2). Note that it's not `NullableIntArray` anymore (too many pytest issues), but I think the new example is clearer anyway. The test suite is _much_ more extensive than I expected. It required adding a lot of extra methods, so even a simple example like this is still pretty large. Whenever a test prompted me to add a new method, I added the test as a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for working on this! I will go over this during the next week.

Comment: Question: what can be done to support the pandas concept of "almost equal" (using atol and rtol parameters)?  Seems like there's no good way to deal with that for complex numeric types beyond complex numbers.  See https://github.com/hgrecco/pint-pandas/issues/26

Comment: On parameterized dtype -- just a note that I think you have a bug passing `units` around. If you test with the non-default dtype in your fixtures, you'll note that `take` and `__getitem__` dont pass units in their constructors.    (also this is one of the most phenomenal SO answers I've ever found!)