# Extending dtype functionality with a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is it possible extend the functionally of a dtype within a dataframe?  for example...

### example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Degrees(np.float64):
    # this string method does not work
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{int(self):03}"


df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12, dtype=Degrees).reshape(4,3)*20,columns=['a','b','c'])
```

### result

```
       a      b      c
0    0.0   20.0   40.0
1   60.0   80.0  100.0
2  120.0  140.0  160.0
3  180.0  200.0  220.0
```

### astype(...)

I would like to by calling `astype(str)` invoke the `Degrees.__str__(...)`

```py
df.astype(str)
```

I realize this does not work and the solution below accomplishes the desired result.  I'm just curious if it's possible, or even worth the hassle.

```py
df.applymap(lambda s:f"{int(s):03}")
# or even
df.applymap(lambda s:str(Degrees(s)))
```

### desired

```
     a    b    c
0  000  020  040
1  060  080  100
2  120  140  160
3  180  200  220
```

Comment: it really depends on how you are using those results. My guess is it's not worth it since you might do computations later and will have to change dtypes

Comment: Also not sure of your exact goal, but you might consider the ExtensionDtype API. See my `AngleDtype` example here: [**Simple example of a pandas ExtensionArray**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972163/13138364) (the example also includes a full ExtensionArray which you can ignore if you only care about the ExtensionDtype)

Comment: The goal being be to allow the same operations as the base dtype. With the exception of the methods that are overwritten by the sub dtype special class methods.  Sorry if I’m screwing up terminology.

Comment: @tdy I just skimmed that post. Its late now but I think that’s what I’m looking for, thank you.

Comment: In `pandas`, columns containing strings are `object` dtype, and the strings are "plain" Python strings.  In contrast `numpy` has a special `Un` string dtype, though it doesn't add much functionality.  I haven't looked at `pandas` extension-dtypes.