# ExtensionDtype is slow for float dtype with 2 kinds of missed data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

I need to have some functionality to contain 2 difference kinds of missed data NC (not computed, reported as missed by user) and ND (not defined, when we do not have data at all, like after join of 2 dataframes).

Based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972163) I created the following code, but the actual problem now is **performance**, which was reduced to 100-1000 times (**0.15s -> 19.49s**)!

```
import operator
from functools import cached_property

import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.arrays import ExtensionArray
from pandas.core.dtypes.base import ExtensionDtype


class NCDvalue:
    na_value = np.NINF

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value:
            try:
                self.value = float(value)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                self.value = self.na_value
        else:
            self.value = np.NaN


@pd.api.extensions.register_extension_dtype
class NCDtype(ExtensionDtype):
    kind = "f"
    na_value = np.NaN
    inf_as_na = True
    _metadata = ()

    @cached_property
    def _is_numeric(self):
        return True

    @cached_property
    def is_numeric_dtype(self) -> bool:
        return True

    @cached_property
    def type(self):
        # The type for a single row of a column
        return float

    @cached_property
    def name(self) -> str:
        """A string representation of the dtype."""
        return "NCDtype"

    @classmethod
    def construct_array_type(cls):
        """Return the array type associated with this dtype."""
        return NCDArray

    @classmethod
    def construct_from_string(cls, string: str):
        """
        See docstring in `ExtensionDType` class in `pandas/core/dtypes/base.py`
        for information about this method.
        """
        if not isinstance(string, str):
            raise TypeError(f"'construct_from_string' expects a string, got {type(string)}")
        # Upstream code uses exceptions as part of its normal control flow and
        # will pass this method bogus class names.
        if string == cls.__name__:
            return cls()
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Cannot construct a '{cls.__name__}' from '{string}'")


class NCDArray(ExtensionArray):
    """Abstract base class for custom 1-D array types."""

    def __init__(self, values, dtype=None, copy=False):
        """Instantiate the array.
        If you're doing any type coercion in here, you will also need
        that in an overwritten __settiem__ method.
        But, here we coerce the input values into Observation.
        """
        self._data = np.array(values, copy=copy).astype(float, copy=copy)  # actual value
        self._replaced_data = self._replace_inf_to_na()
        # self._nc =  # NC or ND
        # present NC / ND argument
        # ignore NC / ND in calculation
        self._dtype = NCDtype()

    @classmethod
    def _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy=False):
        """Construct a new ExtensionArray from a sequence of scalars."""
        if dtype is bool or (isinstance(scalars, np.ndarray) and scalars.dtype.name == "bool"):
            return pd.Series(scalars, dtype=bool)
        return cls(scalars, dtype=dtype)

    @classmethod
    def _from_sequence_of_strings(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy=False):
        """Construct a new ExtensionArray from a sequence of scalars."""
        return cls(scalars, dtype=dtype)

    @classmethod
    def _from_factorized(cls, values, original):
        """Reconstruct an ExtensionArray after factorization."""
        return cls(values)

    # TestSetitemTests
    def __setitem__(self, index: int, value: np.generic) -> None:
        """
        Set one or more values in-place.
        """
        # Check index for TestSetitemTests
        index = pd.core.indexers.check_array_indexer(self, index)

        if isinstance(index, int):
            if isinstance(value, NCDArray):
                if len(value._data) > 1:
                    raise ValueError
                else:
                    value = value._data[0]
            # Upcast to value's type (if needed) for TestMethodsTests
            if self._data.dtype < type(value):
                self._data = self._data.astype(type(value))

        self._data[index] = value

    def __getitem__(self, index: int):
        """
        Select a subset of self.
        """
        if isinstance(index, int):
            return self._data[index]
        else:
            # Check index for TestGetitemTests
            index = pd.core.indexers.check_array_indexer(self, index)
            return type(self)(self._data[index])

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        """Length of this array."""
        return len(self._data)

    def __str__(self):
        def to_str(value):
            if value is np.inf:
                return "NC"
            if np.isnan(value):
                return "ND"
            return str(value)

        return " ".join(map(to_str, self._data))

    # .replace('inf', 'NC').replace('-inf', 'NC').replace('nan', 'ND')
    # def __repr__(self):
    #     data = self._data.tolist()
    #     nc = self.is_nc()
    #     nd = self.is_nd()
    #     # a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1]
    #     # replacements = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 'foo'}
    #     # replacer = replacements.get  # For faster gets.
    #     # print([replacer(n, n) for n in a])
    #
    #     # data = ['NC' if is_nc else value for value, is_nc, is_nd in (data, nc)]
    #     # data = ['ND' if is_nd else value for value, is_nc, is_nd in (data, nd)]
    #
    #     super(NCDArray, self)._formatter()(data)

    def _replace_inf_to_na(self):
        x = self._data
        mask = self.isna()
        masked_array = ma.masked_array(x, mask=mask, fill_value=np.NaN)

        return masked_array.filled()

    @cached_property
    def nbytes(self):
        """The byte size of the data."""
        return self._data.nbytes

    @cached_property
    def dtype(self):
        """An instance of 'ExtensionDtype'."""
        return self._dtype

    def isna(self):
        """A 1-D array indicating if each value is missing."""
        return ~np.isfinite(self._data.astype(float, copy=False))

    def is_nc(self):
        return np.isinf(self._data.array)

    def is_nd(self):
        return np.isnan(self._data.array)

    def take(self, indexer, allow_fill=False, fill_value=None):
        """Take elements from an array.
        Relies on the take method defined in pandas:
        https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e246c3b05924ac1fe083565a765ce847fcad3d91/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L1483
        """
        from pandas.api.extensions import take

        data = self._data
        if allow_fill and fill_value is None:
            fill_value = self.dtype.na_value

        result = take(data, indexer, fill_value=fill_value, allow_fill=allow_fill)
        return self._from_sequence(result)

    # # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    def copy(self):
        """Return a copy of the array."""
        return type(self)(self._data.copy())

    def _apply_operator(self, op, other, recast=False) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Helper method to apply an operator `op` between `self` and `other`.

        Some ops require the result to be recast into AngleArray:
        * Comparison ops: recast=False
        * Arithmetic ops: recast=True
        """
        f = operator.attrgetter(op)

        data = self._replaced_data
        if isinstance(other, NCDArray):
            other = other._replaced_data
        result = f(data)(other)
        return result if not recast else type(self)(result)

    def _apply_operator_if_not_series(self, op, other, recast=False) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Wraps _apply_operator only if `other` is not Series/DataFrame.

        Some ops should return NotImplemented if `other` is a Series/DataFrame:
        https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e7e7b40722e421ef7e519c645d851452c70a7b7c/pandas/tests/extension/base/ops.py#L115
        """
        if isinstance(other, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)):
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return self._apply_operator(op, other, recast=recast)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ne__")
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator("__ne__", other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__lt__")
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator("__lt__", other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__gt__")
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator("__gt__", other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__le__")
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator("__le__", other, recast=False)

    # TestComparisonOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ge__")
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator("__ge__", other, recast=False)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__add__")
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series("__add__", other, recast=True)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__sub__")
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series("__sub__", other, recast=True)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__mul__")
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series("__mul__", other, recast=True)

    # TestArithmeticOpsTests
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__truediv__")
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator_if_not_series("__truediv__", other, recast=True)

    # Required for all ExtensionArray subclasses
    @pd.core.ops.unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._apply_operator("__eq__", other, recast=False)

    @classmethod
    def _concat_same_type(cls, to_concat):
        """Concatenate multiple arrays."""
        return cls(np.concatenate([x._data for x in to_concat]))

    # Test*ReduceTests
    def all(self) -> bool:
        return all(self)

    def any(self) -> bool:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return any(self)

    def sum(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._replaced_data.sum()

    def mean(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._replaced_data.mean()

    def max(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._replaced_data.max()

    def min(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._replaced_data.min()

    def prod(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return self._replaced_data.prod()

    def std(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._replaced_data).std()

    def var(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._replaced_data).var()

    def median(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return np.median(self._replaced_data)

    def skew(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._replaced_data).skew()

    def kurt(self) -> np.generic:  # Test*ReduceTests
        return pd.Series(self._replaced_data).kurt()

    # Test*ReduceTests
    def _reduce(self, name: str, *, skipna: bool = True, **kwargs):
        """
        Return a scalar result of performing the reduction operation.
        """
        f = operator.attrgetter(name)
        return f(self)()

    # TestMethodsTests
    def value_counts(self, dropna: bool = True):
        """
        Return a Series containing descending counts of unique values (excludes NA values by default).
        """
        return pd.core.algorithms.value_counts(self._data, dropna=dropna)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1.0, 2.0, np.inf, np.NaN, np.NINF]})

df1["A"] = df1["A"].astype(dtype=NCDtype())
print("df1:\n", df1)
print("df1.dtypes:\n", df1.dtypes)
print("df1.isna:\n", df1.isna())
print("df.str:", df1["A"].__repr__())
```

As you may see I extend originally missed data (ND, np.NaN) by np.NINF for representation of NC.

We need to make it *float* based, not *object*, to perform some calculations with attention to performance (*float* much quicker then *object*) and *float* do not lead to exceptions dtype with missed values in *object* with `None` during simple operations like `sum` for example.

Does anyone have any idea how to handle slow performance? What exactly I am doing wrong and how to reach original goal?

Comment: Why didn't you show the results of the prints?  Are you expecting us to read and run the code in our heads?  Or run it on our own?  What were you time testing?  Not that any of that really matters.  As far as I can tell these extension dtypes are a `pandas` enhancement, that does nothing to the underlying `numpy` calculations.  Calculations on object dtype arrays are performed at 'list-comprehension' speeds, not in compiled methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample dataframe:

```
In [31]: In [6]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1.0, 2.0, np.inf, np.NaN, np.NINF]})
    ...:    ...:
    ...:    ...: df1["A"] = df1["A"].astype(dtype=NCDtype())
    ...:
```

add a float column for comparison:

```
In [32]: df1['B'] = df1['A'].astype(float)
In [33]: df1
Out[33]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  inf  inf
3  NaN  NaN
4 -inf -inf
```

the dtypes

```
In [34]: df1.dtypes
Out[34]: 
A    NCDtype
B    float64
dtype: object
```

the array derived from it is object dtype, though the arrays from individual columns are float:

```
In [35]: df1.to_numpy()
Out[35]: 
array([[1.0, 1.0],
       [2.0, 2.0],
       [inf, inf],
       [nan, nan],
       [-inf, -inf]], dtype=object)
In [36]: df1['B'].to_numpy()
Out[36]: array([  1.,   2.,  inf,  nan, -inf])
```

I could go on to show that calculations on the 'B' column are a bit faster, and calculations on the arrays, for either, are much faster.